# Java break or exit from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that performs several different tasks. Each task is dependent on the previous one being successful.

If this were a method I might write (long hand) :

```
public boolean outerMethod()
{
    boolean success= performTask();

    if(success == false)
    {
        return false;
    } 

   // more processing here if success == true
}
```

and come out of the `outerMethod` back to the caller, and no further processing takes place

But...

If I am in the `run()` method of a thread and I do something like shown below...

How can I end the current thread there and then?

```
public void run()
{
    boolean success = performTask();

    if( success == false )
    {
        /* here is where I want to exit this thread */
    }   

    // further processing if success == true
}
```

Comment: thread stop() is depreciated .use target instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can simply call `return` without a value to exit a `void` method earlier.

```
public void run() {
    boolean success = performTask();

    if( success == false ){
        return; //ends the thread
    }   
    // further processing if success == true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The execution of the thread is completed when the execution of the `run()` method is done, so you can return normally from that method, just as you would do in your `outerMethod()` (though you simply `return;`, since there is no return value).

Answer (score 2):

thread stop() is depreciated .use target instead.thread will exit when no further works left

```
public void run()
{
    boolean success = performTask();

    if(success)
    {
        // further processing if success == true
    }   

   //thread will exit here
}
```

and side note

use

```
if(success) instead of if(success==true) and use if(!success) instead of  if(success!=true)
```

Comment: This is a better approach. It applies the "return once" principal. Code is generally easier to understand and read if you return (or exit in the case of a void) once at the very end of the method. Having returns and breaks in code is harder to read.

Comment: Yes I normally do use if(success) as you've mentioned. I was just using long-hand in my question for clarity. I gave you a vote though :)